# AspectJ declaremixin with class level annotation not matching

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Good morning,

I have defined a custom annotation that I want to use to mark some classes as Auditable

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Auditable {

}
```

And have declared an aspect to handle all classes marked with this annotation. I am using AspectJ with Eclipse

```
@Aspect
public class AuditableClassAspect extends AbstractAuditableAspect {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

// Makes the bean auditable
@DeclareMixin(value="@Auditable *")
public Auditable auditableBeanFactory(Object instance) {
    // Use a bean delegator as a mixin object
    Auditable mixin = applicationContext.getBean(PersistentDelegate.class);
    mixin.setObject(instance);
    return mixin;
}

@Pointcut("get(* (@Auditable *).*) && this(object)")
public void executionGet(Object object) {}

@Pointcut("set(* (@Auditable *).*) && this(object)")
public void executionSet(Object object) {}  
}
```

Then I have marked a class:

```
@Auditable
public class Report implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4746372287860486647L;

private String companyName;
private Date reportingDate;
```

I am using AspectJ with Spring, and have defined the Aspect in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="com.xxx.aop.AuditableClassAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

My issue is that there is no matching happening. The Aspect doesn't "detect" the Report class as an Auditable class.

In eclipse it doesn't show any matching. At run time I have an exception when I am casting my report in an Auditable interface.

Do you have any idea what there is no match?

For information, if in my code I write
     @DeclareMixin(value="com.xxx.Report")
Then I have a matching and the Aspect works.
Is there something missing with the annotation?

Thanks

Gilles

Comment: Spring will only apply AOP to beans it knows and controls. I suspect that your `Report` class isn't a spring managed class but created by other means.

Comment: Have declared my report as a component. No impact. I am suspecting the syntax @Auditable * not being the right one. All other aspects I have in my code show a matching, except this one

Comment: The fact that it is a component doesn't mean it works. If you are creating new instances yourself, still nothing will happen. If those objects are created outside the scope of spring spring will do nothing.

Comment: If in declare Mixin i use the Report class name, then I get a matching. If instead I use (@Auditable *), then I have no matching. So I suspect my annotation not to be effective

Comment: You must use the FQCN for the annotation just like when using a class.